# Questions about time and space complexity nuances

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, space-complexity

Let's say I have an algorithm, spiral(), that takes an integer n and returns an array containing the integers 1 to n2 in a spiral pattern. i.e.,

```c
spiral(n);
```

iterates over the integers 1 to n^2 and inserts them into a 2d array which it creates and returns. e.g.

```c
spiral(3);
```

returns

```c
[[1,2,3],
 [8,9,4],
 [7,6,5]]
```

Obviously, the time complexity is O(n^2), but what is the space complexity? I would say also O(n^2) as we're allocating that much space as a result of calling the function, but I see in most places like leetcode for questions like this they say that the time complexity is O(1). Does necessary return values not count?

Another smaller question I have is about functions like spiral() above. Let's say there's a function like

```c
returnmbyn(m,n);
```

which returns an array of size m*n, but uses no other memory, and just iterates through and inserts each value in the array iteratively. Do we also consider this function to have a space complexity of O(n^2) and time complexity of O(1)?

Comment: Can you provide a link to where an algorithm that takes a number `n` as input and outputs an array of size `n^2` is declared to be in O(1)?

Comment: @He3lixxx sure, https://leetcode.com/problems/spiral-matrix-ii/solution/ . Just have to scroll down a bit.

Comment: The page says "Time Complexity: O(n^2)" for both implementations given. However, you are right that they do say "Space Complexity: O(1). We use constant extra space for storing cnt". Here, they only consider auxiliary space used by the algorithm, not space used to store the actual result.

Comment: @He3lixxx Right, as far as time complexity is concerned I was only unclear on the returnmbyn(m,n) example, whether or not that was O(n^2). But good to know its only a matter of how auxiliary space is treated vs actual result space for the space complexity. Is it considered more "correct" to only consider auxiliary space? Or is that a less common approach to calculating space complexity?

Comment: [Does space complexity analysis usually include output space?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/83574/does-space-complexity-analysis-usually-include-output-space) goes a bit into detail on that question

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the auxiliary space is referred to as space complexity. Space complexity is the total space required for solving a problem including the input and output memory. But it doesn't make sense to include the input and output spaces when analyzing an algorithm and hence we talk about auxiliary space and call it the "space complexity" of that algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you an example. Suppose you are given this problem:

> Given 0 <= i, j < n, find M[i][j], where M is a nxn matrix that looks like this:

```
| 1 1 1 1 ... 1 1 |
| 1 2 2 2 ... 2 2 |
| 1 2 3 3 ... 3 3 |
| 1 2 3  .        |
|   ⋮       .    ⋮ |
| 1 2 3 ....... n |
```

How would you do that? Of course you could easily write such matrix in the memory, which would take you O(n^2) time and space, since you need n^2 operations to fill the matrix and n^2 slots to hold in the memory.

The point is: do you really need to store a matrix to know what is inside the matrix? In this case, this matrix can be easily represented as a function:

```
f(i, j) = min(i, j) + 1
```

Thus, with O(1) time and space, you can tell what is in `M[i][j]` without storing the matrix itself.

The trick of these kinds of question is to think about the function that gives you what is inside each slot of the matrix without having to actually fill it.